# Actualizar barra de navegación después de login PHP

Tags: php, html

Hace poco me tope con el problema de no poder actualizar la barra de navegación de mi aplicativo después de un logueo correcto.
El código de la vista es el siguiente el cual verifica si la variable de sesión existe y además si es 'verdadera' y dependiendo de dicho valor carga alguno de los archivos php que se le indica:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-options">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
                        include 'navbar/navbar_logout.php';
                    }
                    else{
                        include 'navbar/navbar_login.php';
                    }                       
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

El siguiente fragmento de código es el que verifica si los datos del usuario son correctos:

```
<?php
session_start();

require("controllers/CUsuario.php");

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $username = $_POST['tbx_email'];
    $password = $_POST['tbx_password'];

    $obj_user = new CUsuario();
    if($obj_user->Check_User($username, $password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    }
}
```

?>

La idea es que una vez el usuario se loguea la barra de navegación cambie (con respecto a sus items), sin embargo a pesar de ingresar los datos correctos la barra de navegación sigue igual.

Espero alguién pueda ayudarme a solucionar mi problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elimina las sesiones del navegador, modifica el siguiente código e inicia sesión otra vez:

```
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
                        include 'navbar/navbar_logout.php';
                    }
                    else{
                        include 'navbar/navbar_login.php';
                    }                       
                ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ... tu consejo me ayudó a solucionar mi problema.