# Obtener username de session en cualquier archivo?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, session

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicacion donde el usuario registra unos datos y quiero que se quede registrado el usuario en el registro pero no logro conseguirlo.

1.- El Usuario inicia session (login.php) y tengo un formulario oculto que manda el username a otro archivo POST

```
echo "Bienvenido $username
<form action='add_retiro.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' class='form-control' id='username' name='username' 
value='$username'  required>
<input type='submit' value='Empezar'/>
";
```

2.- El 2do archivo recibe el username (add_registro.php)

```
<?php
$time = time();
$username = $_POST['username'];
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
} else {
echo "Inicia Session<br>";
echo "<br><a href='http://web.xyz/index.html'>Login</a>";
exit;
}

$now = time();
$fechaguardada = $_SESSION["expire"];
$tiempo_transcurrido = $now-$fechaguardada;

if($tiempo_transcurrido >= 60000) {
session_destroy();

header('Location: http://web.xyz/index.html');
exit;
 }
?>

<html>
<form action="add_retiro1.php" method="post"><h2>Deposito de Retiros</h2>

<input class="large" type="number" id="inputtext2" name="inputtext2"  
placeholder="Escribe el Numero de Retiro" required/>


<input class="large" type="number" id="inputnumber1" name="inputnumber1" 
placeholder="Escribe el Monto del Retiro" required/>

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputtext3" name="inputtext3" 
value="<?php echo $username ?>" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required />

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputtext4" name="inputtext4"  
value="<?php  echo date("d-m-Y (H:i:s)", $time -18000); ? >" 
placeholder="Hora y Fecha" required />


<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/></div>

</form>
```

Con esto se Registra correctamente en la bd
Despues del registro el archivo php que hace la funcion de insertar en la db redirecciona  al archivo add_registro.php

Pero al volver a capturar otro registro el Usuario me aparece en blanco ya que 
$username = $_POST['username']; YA NO TIENE VALOR ya que fue una redireccion

QUE SOLUCION ME RECOMIENDAN?

abra alguna manera de obtener el username de la session para utilizarlo en cualquier archivo?

Helppppp......

Comment: no guardes las variables en $_POST crea las variables de sesion y asi puedes usarla tambien a nivel global, la guradas asi $_SESSION['username'] = $username; y como la guardas la puedes consultar de la misma forma

Comment: observa este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15206/actualizar-barra-de-navegaci%C3%B3n-despu%C3%A9s-de-login-php

Comment: Muchas gracias esto soluciono mi problema

Answer (score 1):

El código que muestras es un poco raro o incompleto.

Vamos al lio, puedes hacer la persistencia de datos de varias maneras pero me centrare en 1 que veo que utilizas con conocimiento o no, [Sesiones](http://php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php).

Las sesiones permiten hacer persistencia de datos mientras dure la sesión la forma de utilizarlas es simple

archivo_1.php

```
<?php
// indicamos a PHP que vamos a usar sesiones
session_start();
// creamos una variable de sesion
$_SESSION['miVariable'] = 'Este string sera guardado en la variable de sesion';
header('Location: otro_archivo.php');
```

otro_archivo.php

```
<?php
// indicamos a PHP que vamos a usar sesiones
session_start();
// imprimimos el contenido de sesion
echo $_SESSION['miVariable']; // Este string sera guardado en la variable de sesion
```